# In C#, can assignment and parameter passing happen in a single statement?

Tags: c#

I am trying to do

```
        string answer = (5 + 6).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
```

I would like to find out if assignment and parameter passing can happen simultaneously in a single statement for C#. The compiler doesn't like the following code.

```
        Console.WriteLine(string answer = (5 + 6).ToString());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would like to find out if assignment and parameter passing can happen simultaneously in a single statement for C#.

They can, but variable declaration can't. This code is not legal:

```
Console.WriteLine(string answer = (5 + 6).ToString());
```

But this code is legal:

```
string answer;
Console.WriteLine(answer = (5 + 6).ToString());
```

And thanks to assignment chainging, it will output the value `11`. But it's probably not the best coding style you could use. For preference, I'd write it like this:

```
string answer = (5 + 6).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(answer);
```

It's also not best to think of it as "simultaneous". They are in the same C# statement, but won't be in the same IL statement when compiled, and are not atomic.

Comment: What would be the best coding style?

Comment: Thanks Joel. It seems like I was already having the best coding style in the first place. I shouldn't overly compact the code.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**: Never mind, I am rusty apparently. Check out the other answer: **assignment expressions do exist in C#, but they cannot contain variable declarations.**

In C#, assignment is a statement and not an expression. Statements that are not expressions do not have values (unlike C++, where an assignment has a value, namely, the newly assigned value). This is mainly to prefer errors such as `if (x=5) ...`, since `x=5` cannot have a value, this code will fail to build.

If you want to **declare**, **assign**, and then **use**, you're pretty much out of luck, as declaration cannot be used as an expression.

If you only want to **assign** and **use**, then using a function with a `ref` parameter could take care of it.

Example:

```
T AssignAndGet<T>(ref T variable, T result) {
    variable = result;
    return result;
}
```

which could be used as:

```
string x;
Console.WriteLine(AssignAndGet(x, (5+3).ToString()));
```